# ListBox - Checked Item property

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ListBox` of `CheckBox`es. What I want is that whenever I check or uncheck one of these `CheckBox`es some code should be executed. I have tried this

XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Stations, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStation}" />
```

C#

```
private void GetStations()
{
    foreach (var stationName in _databaseService.GetStations())
    {
        Stations.Add(new CheckBox() { Content = stationName });
    }
}

private string selectedStation;
public string SelectedStation
{
    get { return this.selectedStation; }
    set
    {
        this.selectedStation = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedStation");
        //my code here
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that the `SelectedItem` property doesn't work with checking `CheckBox`es. It only reacts to selected the item. Is there a property of `ListBox` that reacts to `CheckBox` checks? What is the proper way to accomplish this?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Hey I'm not sure why you use a `ListBoX` with `CheckBox`es inside. There is a specified element for this, the `CheckedListBox`. With this element you should be able to use the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Answer (score 0):

Why you bind `ListBox` if you want to get reactiong from `CheckBox`es?
In XAML bind `CheckBox`es. And have a bool variable like `isChecked` or something like that. With that flag you can change your `ListBox` and execute a code whenever a `CheckBox` is checked.

And keep in mind that you can always use indexes for those `CheckBox`es.